# How to display photos based on their datecreated

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Thanks for help!
I have an app where users upload photos daily. In the UI, I have a Carousel (parent widget) and a GridView (child widget). Based on the dateCreated, I need to display photos as follows:

For example, on Carsoule (page 1 : 23.02.2023), I need to display a GridView that includes all the photos that users have taken on that date. However, currently, my code just displays all the photos in the Carousel pages, which is understandable. Can you please advise me on how I can display photos based on their dateCreated on the GridView?

```
class SugarPhotoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SugarPhotoPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SugarPhotoPage> createState() => _SugarPhotoPageState();
}

class _SugarPhotoPageState extends State<SugarPhotoPage> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _photoStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('photos')
      .orderBy('dateCreated')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _photoStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return CarouselSlider.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                itemBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) {
                  final data = snapshot.data?.docs[itemIndex].data()!
                      as Map<String, dynamic>;

                  return Stack(
                    children: [
                      GridViewCustom(
                        imgUrl: data['imgUrl'],
                        itemCount: 5,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 70,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 18, 18),
                        child: Text(
                          '${pageViewIndex} ${itemIndex} Date:  ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data['dateCreated'])}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  viewportFraction: 1.0,
                  enlargeCenterPage: false,
                  height: height,
                ),
              );
            }
            return const Text('Loading');
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to show the photos `group by` or `sort by`?

Comment: would be any different in UI ?

Comment: Yes. `Sort by` only sorts the list and show in a single list. `Group by` sorts and shows the images with date label, lets consider Today and yesterday, Images taken yesterday will be listed under label yesterday, and images taken today will be listed under label today.

Comment: Alex , Can i send you a message  ?

Comment: Yeah, sure Dani

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to specify the correct order of dateCreated,

While uploading image to firebase, set the `dateCreated` like

```
'dateCreated': DateTime.now(),
```

And you can access it like this.

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _photoStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('photos')
      .orderBy('dateCreated', descending: true)
      .snapshots();
```

Comment: Hey Thanks ALI , actually there is a Calendar widget where use pick the time and  there is no difference if its descending, or ascending, what I'm struggling is, it load all the photo in Carsoule what I need to do is load photo based on the same datecreated on GridView